# How to parse EntityReference

Tags: java, xml, dom, entityreference

I am parsing an XML file with a DOM parser and here is the corresponding .dtd:

```
<!ELEMENT Concept (%ConceptReference;, TermList)>
...
<!ENTITY  % ConceptReference "(ConceptUI,ConceptName,ConceptUMLSUI?)">
```

I already parsed `ConceptReference` into an `EntityReference` object. The point I am stuck is: how do I get `ConceptName` and `ConceptUI`?

Comment: I'm a bit lost. A DTD is not valid XML. So how are you able to read it with an XML parser?

Comment: I am reading the actual XML file, .dtd is the structural description. I am lost working with EntityReference interface.

Comment: Ok, fine. What have you actually tried? Did you use the [`EntityDeclaration`](http://glassfish.java.net/nonav/javaee5/api/javax/xml/stream/events/EntityDeclaration.html) through [`#getDeclaration()`](http://glassfish.java.net/nonav/javaee5/api/javax/xml/stream/events/EntityReference.html#getDeclaration())?